# for him to run VS that he runs

Tags: grammar

1. It is easy for him to run.
2. It is easy that he runs.
   What is the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: What does the second sentence mean? It's hardly normal English.

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence may be transformed into a 'canonical' sentence whose meaning is easy to understand:

> For him to run is easy *which may also be phrased*
>   To run is easy for him.

That is, he finds running easy.

Your second sentence is not obviously idiomatic or grammatical when it is transformed:

> That he runs is easy.

You have to really strain to come up with a situation where that makes sense. For instance:

> **A:** It's hard to pin Jason down. Whenever I approach him, he runs.
>   **B:** Oh, that he runs is easy: you just have to catch him in the elevator. What's hard is to make sense of that techno-gibberish he speaks.

Another, equally far-fetched interpretation leaves the sentence untransformed:

> **A:** We're thinking of recruiting Jason for the pentathlon. I know he can shoot and swim and ride and swim—how does he run?
>   **B:** Oh, it’s easy that he runs: very graceful and effortless.

This interpretation is more plausible if you read **B** with an Irish accent.

Answer (score -2):

Is it just me or is the second sentence completely wrong?

I guess my answer is this : the difference between the two sentences is that the first one is correct English :)

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer???

Comment: it's my answer : the difference between the two is that one of the sentences is incorrect. This is merely my answer and it might be wrong, but it's an answer.

Comment: That's not a very thorough answer really. Please edit it to include *why* it is wrong if tall possible. (n.b., I agree that it's weird but it's not inconceivable as a sentence -- given some tenuous circumstances).

Comment: The thing is I don't even understand what this sentence could mean.  I'm sorry you think my answer is so useless. I don't know how to make it better because I don't understand how this sentence is made and how it's supposed to work... That's why my answer was so short.

Comment: @Tonik There is no need to answer a question that you don't know the answer for (can't explain). Just lurk around and see what other people say!

Comment: I think I am allowed to answer what I think is right, regardless. If you want to give me negative points, fine that's your right too. I could tell you there's no need telling me there's no need to express myself on this question, because I did so apparently there was a need. But what's the point, are you going to delete your comment because I tell you there's no need nxx? You consider that I don't know the answer, that's not my point of view. Let's be open minded, shall we? This is not war.